# I want to test my app for to hit a 500 Internal server and when it does I want to show my custom error page

Tags: angularjs, testing, nginx, custom-error-pages

On my angularjs app, I have defined custom error pages on nginx server like for 404 and 500 errors and I have changed the certain code accordingly I need to test whether it shows the 500 error custom page, How to test my app to hit 500 error and show my custom error page, Any tests to check the 500 error on angular js app??

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please add some codes.

Comment: You're app is not supposed to hit HTTP 500 provided that your app is a single page app (unless it's the 1st request and it uses some serverside tech to provide the index file); therefore, your http request to your backend api that should hit 500 and for that, you can write an http interceptor.

Comment: From what I know is that it is generated through internal server error, I have made some modifications on nginx.conf file in nginx server so I get that error but couldn't find any

Comment: @LenilsondeCastro I've written the http interceptor and the application was running without error and also have given condition if status.code === 500 I've pointed to a route using $location.path(), but to test whether it reaches that particular route I need to hit a 500 Internal error, so what to do for that?

Comment: At routing level you only have to deal with 404 Not Found usually, and in case your api hits 500 Internal Server Error, your interceptor could simple redirect the app to a custom page dedicated to describe the error through your router. I don't know if I understood well, but context is a bit unclear so bear with me.

Comment: I've redirected the 404 error page in .otherwise({templateUrl : '/404.html'}); It's working fine, Now I need to test 500 error

Answer (score 0):

```
In Your controller use like this:
$http.get('dataaa.json').then(function(data){
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data.data));
    }, function(error) {
        if(error.status==404){
            $location.path("/yourErrorPage for 404");
        }
        if(error.status==500){
            $location.path("/yourErrorPage for 500");
        }
        console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
        //alert(JSON.stringify(error));
        //deferred.reject(error.data);
    });
```

Comment: I've done this already, Now I want to test whether I reach the custom 500 error page if it occurs, what are the steps to check whether my app reaches 500 error

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what you are looking for is to test a 500 error page BUT with an error code from your front... Which seems impossible as @lenilsondc was mentioning.

What you could test is returning a 500 error code from your backend.
You would ideally send a 500 code from there that could be(?) intercepted by Nginx and send the 500 page you want.

Other possibilities would involve errors in code like Promise failed and catched ideally which would not involve any other error page as mentionned also...

Maybe you would need some more global view of where come the http (error) codes ?